# undefined index

Tags: errors

I upgraded to the latest version of WordPress and now for some reason when I go to the menus page and it only seems to happen there, I get an error saying

Notice: Undefined index: eventmeta_noncename in /home3/themes/savior/functions.php on line 1399

Here is the code. Line 1399 would be line 4 in the code

http://pastebin.com/rNR7sMGP

I can't figure out why it's an undefined index.

Comment: It would be line 20 in that code, not 4. It means that you are comparing the value of a (special) variable, but you are not checking if that variable is set first.

Comment: maybe I am missing something. I thought it was created and then set with the input fields above that line. What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have solved the issue.. Checking to see that it is set.

```
 if ( !isset( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
return $post->ID;
 }
```